# How can I draw a line to an array?

Tags: arrays, drawing, line, processing

I'd like to store a mouse trail (or other visual data), without it being drawn to the screen.

How can I do the following, but save the display data to an Arrary so it's not drawn to the stage?

```
line(mouseX, mouseY, pmouseX, pmouseY);
```

I have a suspicion I need to toggle between different display data each draw() by:

- clearing the screen
- loading target display data
- drawing to the screen
- store back out to target data

I'm not sure how to go about it yet or if there's a better approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [PGraphics](http://processing.org/reference/PGraphics.html) to draw lines to different display (you can switch it on/off by pressing any key) and `Arraylist` to store position of mouse you can achieve something like this:

```java
PGraphics pg;
ArrayList<Integer> points = new ArrayList();
boolean visible = true;

void setup() {
  size(400, 400);
  pg = createGraphics(width, height);
}

void draw() {
  background(100);

  if(points.size() >= 100){
    points.remove(0);
    points.remove(1);
  }  
  points.add(mouseX);
  points.add(mouseY);

  pg.beginDraw();
  pg.background(100);
  for(int i = 2; i < points.size()-4; i += 2){
    pg.stroke(255/100*(i+1));
    pg.line(points.get(i), points.get(i+1), points.get(i+2), points.get(i+3));
  }
  pg.endDraw();

  if(visible)
    image(pg, 0, 0);  
}

void keyPressed() {
  visible = !visible;
}
```

Comment: I hadn't read about PGraphic yet, thank you! Being able to draw directly to the object is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 3):

@Majlik example is really cool (voted up). Just to add that you don't need a PGraphic if you only want to store the data. And you can use  PVector to store the data in mouseMoved().

here is my attempt ;)

```java
ArrayList <PVector> points = new ArrayList <PVector>();
boolean print = false;

void setup(){
  size(400,400);
  background(255);
}


void draw(){
  if(print && points.size()>1){
    for(int i = 0; i < points.size()-1; i++){
      float stX =  points.get(i).x;
      float stY =  points.get(i).y;
      float ndX =  points.get(i+1).x;
      float ndY =  points.get(i+1).y;

      line(stX, stY, ndX, ndY);
    }
    print = false;
  }
}


void mouseMoved(){
  points.add(new PVector (mouseX, mouseY));
}


void keyPressed(){
  if(key == ' ' ){
    background(255);
    print = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Using `PVector` is cleaner solution :)